# Hive and Cassandra integration using CqlStorageHandler

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, hive, bigdata

I referred this git project for integrating cassandra data using hive table.I copied the appropriate cassandra jars into the hive lib folder.But while running the query against cassandra I'm getting the following error.Please help me to resolve it.

https://github.com/milliondreams/hive/tree/cas-support-cql/cassandra-handler

hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE messages(row_key string, col1 string, col2 string)

> ```
> STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql.CqlStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES("cql.primarykey" = "row_key")
> TBLPROPERTIES ("cassandra.ks.name" = "mycqlks", "cassandra.ks.stratOptions"="'DC':1, 'DC2':1",
> "cassandra.ks.strategy"="NetworkTopologyStrategy");
> ```
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getSchema(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/api/Table;)Ljava/util/Properties;
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql.CqlManager.createColumnFamily(CqlManager.java:238)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql.CqlManager.createCFIfNotFound(CqlManager.java:189)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql.CqlStorageHandler.preCreateTable(CqlStorageHandler.java:247)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:462)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.createTable(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:455)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:74)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.createTable(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:596)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:3776)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:256)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:144)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:57)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1355)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1139)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:945)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:259)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:216)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:413)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:756)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:614)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
>   FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

Answer (score 1):

Which version of hive are you using?

It has to be hive 0.9 as per https://github.com/milliondreams/hive/tree/cas-support-cql/cassandra-handler

I think you are using version >= 0.11.0

Version 0.9.0: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/tags/release-0.9.0/metastore/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/MetaStoreUtils.java

Version 0.10.0: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/tags/release-0.10.0/metastore/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/MetaStoreUtils.java

Version 0.11.0: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/tags/release-0.11.0/metastore/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/metastore/MetaStoreUtils.java

Single argument method - org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getSchema is missing in 0.11.0

Comment: Hi, Where I have to place this source file specify the exact location. After the source file is copied it is required to rebuild the package with mvn package.